# How to get my dropdown menu and hover effect right?

Tags: html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I've built a horizontal menu with drop-down capabilities and it's almost working correctly. I only have 2 problems with it, which i can't find the right method to solve these issues:

1. The distance between the main menu links and the dropdown menu are a little bit to far, so when you try to move your mouse to the dropdown menu it just disappears.I know by changing the **`#submenu_dames{top:34px}`** into a smaller number wil bring it closer to the links,but that also means that it will cover the main menu grey line beneath. Which the dropdown must stay under the line.
2. I've tried to change the background-color of the main menu links with the CSS hover effect. But what happens is that the background-color doesn't fill up with the right width and height.

**Here is my code in action:**

http://jsfiddle.net/flasy_kid/bFBcg/

Answer (score 0):

You should also change it to use classes rather than ID's so your CSS can be more generic, but this solves the two problems you listed: http://jsfiddle.net/bFBcg/2/

Comment: your right about the classes and ID's, but this isn't really working. The problem remains that if you don't move fast enough you dont get the chance to move into the dropdown menu. And the dropdown menu position is showing above the main menu bottom line. If you test it in a browser you can see what i'm talkin about.

Comment: Then keep tweaking the position until it is where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine, http://jsfiddle.net/bFBcg/6/

```
li.menu_item {
    display:inline-block; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding-right: 20px; 
    position:relative; 
}
#menu li a {
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:black;
}
#menu_main {
    border-color:#E2E2E2;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width:1px 0 1px 0;
}
#submenu_dames { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:550px; 
    border-left:1px solid black; 
    border-right:1px solid black; 
    border-bottom:1px solid black; 
    background:#F6F6F6; display:none;
}
#submenu_heren { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:550px; 
    border-left:1px solid black; 
    border-right:1px solid black; 
    border-bottom:1px solid black; 
    background:#F6F6F6; 
    display:none;
}
.menu_item:hover #submenu_dames {
    display:block;
}
.menu_item:hover #submenu_heren {
    display:block;
}
.submenu { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
}
.submenu li { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none;
}
.submenu_vak {
    float:left; 
    width:150px; 
    margin: 5px; 
    padding: 5px;
}
.submenu_titel {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.menu_item:hover {
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

Comment: just as with swider's solution above this isn't really working. I suggest testing it in a webbrowser to see what i mean.